# To find the sum using indicator function?

Tags: r

```
X=c(5.3552,5.0212,11.1375,10.6883,0.0000,1.4795,0.0000,0.0000,0.8646,8.5751,4.8460,1.3602,20.3108,0.0000,20.883,0.000,0.000,11.3210,7.707,0.000)
Y=c(2.746,2.776,2.785,2.788,2.777,2.778,2.777,-2.0798,2.546,-1.3201,0.905,2.777,-11.7463,-0.2909,-0.2417,0.1206,2.7777,2.3524,1.7479,1.5524)
```

I define a indicator function Z is given as: Z takes 1 when X>0 and takes 0 when X=0.
Here I am unable to write the R code for the following expression

```
(Z-1)*X+Z*Y
```

Please help me in this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: `(as.numeric(X>0) - 1) * X + as.numeric(X>0) * Y` ? But (Z-1) * X will always be equal to 0... (if X>0, then Z -1 = 0 ; if X = 0 then (Z-1) * X = 0) So `as.numeric(X>0) * Y` should be enough. Are you sure of your formula ?

Comment: @arunkumar This question has nothing to do with writing a function nor with a function named sum, those tags are irrelevant to this question. Read the tags excerpt before adding them to questions please. (And when editing, try to remove the greetings/tank you lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a indicator function Z using ifelse function where Z takes 1 when X>0 and takes 0 when X=0.

```
Z <- ifelse(X>0 , 1 , 0)

(Z-1)*X+Z*Y

[1]   2.7460   2.7760   2.7850   2.7880   0.0000   2.7780   0.0000   0.0000   2.5460  -1.3201   0.9050   2.7770 -11.7463   0.0000  -0.2417
[16]   0.0000   0.0000   2.3524   1.7479   0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Arun kumar mahesh

Comment: can i get an upvote / can u accept my answer  @saroja

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Z = rep(0, length(X))
Z[X>0] = 1
Z
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
(Z-1)*X+Z*Y
#[1]   2.7460   2.7760   2.7850   2.7880   0.0000   2.7780   0.0000   0.0000   2.5460  -1.3201   0.9050   2.7770 -11.7463   0.0000  -0.2417   0.0000   0.0000
#[18]   2.3524   1.7479   0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much.